# How to delete the documents based on the specific column or key names in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

Mistakenly I have imported a CSV file into the wrong collection. Is there any way to delete those documents based on the imported CSV headers?

Comment: yes, it is possible

Comment: Yes, something like `db.collection.deleteMany({specific_header: {$exists: true}})`